# Pandas: Adding Values from a list into a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df2

         A
    0
```

I have a list that looks like this:

```
stuff = ['apples', 'oranges']
```

I want to add the records from my list into my data frame so that my output looks like this:

```
                          A
0     ['apples', 'oranges']
```

Any suggestions? I am not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.at`:

```
df.at[0, 'A'] = ['apples', 'oranges']
```

Comment: For accessing "cells", use `df.at`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
import pandas as pd
list = [['oranges', 'apples']]
df= pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = list
```

Comment: df['A'] = list will define the 'A' column